# Responsive E-mail

Tags: css, outlook, html-email, responsiveness

I'm making a responsive email. My code works everywhere except for Outlook 7 & 10. I know it has to do with the padding and margin, and I tried everything to fix this, but it's still not working. Does anyone has a solution for this ? 
I tried what they said : https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/outlookcom-margins/

So i changed all my margin tags from : `margin-left:5%; to margin:0 0 0 5%;`

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Posting the would be nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your code?  Depending on what you are trying to add margin and padding to, there are a number of ways to insure this works across email clients, even the dreaded Outlook.

If you are trying to add padding to your images, don't bother.  Outlook 2007 and 2010 will strip padding from images.  If you think margins would do the trick, consider that outlook.com doesn't support margin.

For images the best way to insure that you have space around your images is to add faux margins by adding transparency around your image before you save it.

For `<td>` use padding.  Padding in `<td>` is supported on all email clients.

```
<td style="padding-top:12px;padding-right:12px;padding-bottom:12px;padding-left:12px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup. You may find  supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties described in the following articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are emailing to any of the Outlooks or Outlook.com. You really cannot use margins effectively for cross-client rendering. In general, I usually do not recommend margin as it can be unstable despite its support across email clients.

Your best bet is to use nested tables with padding on TD tags to build your margins. It is far from elegant, but allows for the best rendering.

If you want/need to use the margins, then I would write conditional code in for Outlook to create a table with the padding around these areas to make sure it displays correctly in Outlook.  Again, far from elegant, but should be stable.